# Problem with light in Unity2D

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I'm new to working with lights in Unity, I watched a lot of tutorials and decided to use URP. It seems like I have everything set up, but when I set the lighting, the light doesn’t fall on the textures, but rather paints them as if. Maybe I don't understand something?

[image]

[image]

An example of what I want to do
[image]

Comment: Paints them as if what? What is your expected outcome, and how does what you observe differ from that?

Comment: I expect the light to shine on the textures, but instead it just makes the textures a solid color. I don't understand what this is about

Comment: What would shining on the textures look like? Can you mock up or find an example of the look you want to achieve?

Comment: @DMGregory I changed the post, I want to put some light on my game as well